# Misconduct report

Tags: teaching-assistant

I am teaching at the university, and I am giving Calculus 1 for first year engineering students. 
I am having a problem with some students, their behavior in the class is inappropriate: making noise, speaking in the class with their classmates, not writing or even paying attention. As a consequence of such behaviors and in order to keep my class controlled, I kick them out the class.

For this, I should send a misconduct report to the director of the university. Our university has distributed a misconduct sample for all instructors, however, I have difficulty describing the misconduct.

The idea is that it is difficult for me to describe their behavior in English since it is not my native language.

Would someone help me how to start the description of the misconduct?  and what to write exactly?

I already did some researches on google, but they were useless, and as this site is concerned with Academic ideas, I think my problem can be entitled under academic problems.

Comment: Can you state what country this is, so we have some context about the culture? In the US, I would think that a formal misconduct report for such behavior would be excessive, unless the behavior is really flagrant or persistent.  And "not writing" and "not paying attention" are not generally treated as misconduct at all unless the student is disturbing others.

Comment: @NateEldredge Infact I in Lebanon, a small country in the Middle East.  As you said "not writing" and "not paying attention" is not a seriuos misconduct. But in a large class ( about 40 students), studnets that are not writinting and not paying attention they will get bored quickly and strat doing noise, speaking with each other, or do some clowning, as the lecture is about one hour and fourty minutes.

Comment: Are you required to write a report or do you choose to do it as an additional reprimand?

Comment: Voting to close...everyone is answering the (more interesting) question about whether this is a good idea, but OP's question is about the mechanics of writing such a report in English (which is not really on-topic here).

Comment: How can you teach in a language you are not quite familiar with?

Comment: @Alchimista I didnot say that I am not familiar  to English. Scientifically I am very good in English, but I find difficulty describing  such inappropriate behaviuors. In fact, these behaviuors I cannot even describe in my own language.

Comment: I see. I would try to impose your prrsonality and speak with a colleague before official moves, as others said. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

> I am having a problem with some students, their behavior in the class is inappropriate: making noise, speaking in the class with their classmates, not writing or even paying attention. As a consequence of such behaviors and in order to keep my class controlled, I kick them out the class.
>
> For this, I should send a misconduct report to the director of the university.

While it seems a little over the top to me, I am going to assume you were justified in kicking the students out and I am also going to assume that triggered a mandatory filing of a misconduct report. I would write a draft report that says exactly what you said. I would then pass that by a senior colleague and ask if it is necessary to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find it under "academic problems". Every university might have different policies regarding how to handle students interrupting the course (there is no universal guideline).

I would ask a senior colleague "What is considered a misconduct that qualifies to be reported?".
Your colleague's answer will help you qualify the type of misconduct and you will know what to write in your report.

And for your own sake do not kick students out of the room regularly if you do not know the university culture and regulations. From your question I assume you are still getting used to the university that you are teaching at.Instead of keeping your class in control you might get a nice nickname and a headache from your head of department.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than put the blame on students, you might look at what you are doing in the face to face sessions. For some reason at least some of your students don't believe that it is worth listening or participating. Likely they are bored.

One solution to such things is to force the students into a more active learning situation in which they naturally participate, rather than simply listening to a lecture. They don't seem to think that the information they are getting is worth it.

I once had a couple of teachers who thought, quite literally, that students were supposed to faithfully copy everything they wrote rather than understanding it. In one case, with only two students, we simply copied from his previously written notes. There was a lot of copying, but no learning.

It is possible that even good lectures are posed at a level that isn't appropriate for the students. It might be low, hence boring, or too high, hence frustrating.

Look to your teaching methodology. Passive learning is seldom very useful for very many students. Learning involves working with and reinforcing ideas, not just hearing ideas from another. Even marvelous lecturers can be less effective in actually *teaching* rather than just entertaining. It is a subtle issue.

Answer (score 0):

The term "academic misconduct" usually refers to things like plagiarism or ghosting. Disturbing behaviour in class is annoying but in my opinion does not come under the same umbrella as academic misconduct. In many more traditional (old-school) universities it would be considered normal to kick disturbing students out of the class; however, I never heard on anyone filing academic misconduct report on them afterwards. In many places kicking students out is seemed as a certain weakness of a lecturer and would be grumbled upon.